# SSRS 2012 Two Tables each using its own DataSet, second table disappears and does not show in report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, dataset

I hope somebody can help me out here. I have created a report using multiple datasets. Table A uses dataset A, and table B used dataset B. Now, I created table A, and need the second table to be identical, so in Report Designer I copied the table, pasted it back in (this is now table B), and then made sure that table B used dataset B by highlighting the table and changing the dataset used in its properties.
I run the report and table A looks great, but table B is nowhere to be seen. So I deleted the fields and reentered them just to be sure, but once the report was ran, the tables was not visible again.

Ok, I thought, so I deleted Table B, and created a new table that was the same, but again, once I ran the report table B failed to appear.

Why wont the second table show up in the report? This is driving me crazy!

I have two sets of parameters that the user chooses from to populate the tables, one set of parameters ends up populating table A, the other sets populates table B. The parameters are independent of each other.

I hope I've given enough info, Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel, and I think SSRS is on SP2 CU6. That is what SQL Server 2012 is up to so I assume SSRS 2012 will be the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "dataset" as compared to "table"? A table is a "data set".

Comment: Also could we have a schema of these two tables? You may not be joining them properly.

Comment: Hello, perhaps I should have said Tablix instead of tables? I have noticed that of the two sets of parameters (each set relating to its own Tablix and filtering via their own independent datasets), only the first set of parameters used to populate Table A are working, the second  set of parameters are not populating the second Tablix.

Comment: A few things to try : If you remove the filtering on DatasetB or TablixB (depending on where you filter) do you get anything? I think the first step s just to make sure you you are not filtering out all the data by mistake. Next, inside the tablix, try adding a header row and putting some text in it to see if that appears. Next, check you don't have any visibility/hidden properties set on the rows or at the tablix level. Once we have answers to these we might be able to narrow it down.

Comment: I think the gotcha is in your statement - "The parameters are independent of each other.". So TableB will not populate if only the parameters are entered to give you TableA. How about sharing the SQL for both the datasets in the report designer?

Comment: @Canadean_AS I am filtering at the database level, there is no filtering on the parameter or the tablix. When I run the report the headers do actually show up. I have nothing configured to be hidden or toggled either, these are all false.

Comment: @Fernando68 To clarify, when I say independant of each other, I mean the two sets of parameters are independent of each other, not all dependent of one another. So the first set of parameters all relate to Table A, and filter off one another (each parameter in the set has its own dataset, which I'm sure you know has to happen) and its own base dataset that populates its table (A), then the same for the other set.

Comment: One thing that may be an issue is, as I have both tables in the same report, SSRS has renamed the fields, as it cannot have the same field name twice, so in Table A (which works well) a field is DatabaseName, but in Table B that fails to populate, its DatabaseName1. Could this be an issue? Thank you everyone for your help so far.

Comment: @Fernando68 I am using Inner Joins for all tables. From a SQL Query perspective, and getting the required result. So I feel like the issue is at the report level.

Comment: Can post the RDL and some sample data so we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe table B appears in the second page. Have you checked it?

[image: second page SSRS]

To prevent this situation mark **Keep together on one page if possible** option in the table properties.

Comment: No, I thought that might have been it but that is not happening, also each Tablix is only three columns long, and containing only one row. I am just trying to get it working with minimal fields first, then add more later when I have worked this issue out.